# ng-repeat behaviour with $watch

Tags: php, angularjs, templates, laravel-4

I am newbie to AngularJs. I am using AngularJS as front end and Laravel As backend.
I have a situation where I want page to be refreshed on ajax success (when user post data).

I have template `index.blade.php` like this :

```
@extends(layout)
 @section
```

```
 header page
  post page 
  main page 
  footer page
```

```
@endsection
```

Now thing is that User is posting update from post page and 
on that success i want data to be refreshed which is on main page

```
function addpost ($scope, $http){

$scope.loadData = function(){
            $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
            $http.post( baseurl+"alldata").success(function(data)
            {
              $scope.posts = data;
         });
             }


                     $scope.addComment = function(post){

        if("undefined" != post.hoot){
        // Angular AJAX call            
        $http({
        method : "POST",
        url :baseurl+ "url",
        data : "post="+post
        }).success(function(data){
             $scope.posts = data;//json response

        // here i want page to be refreshed or div refresh of sub-main    page 

            });`
            $scope.post = ' ';`
            }
            }
                     $scope.loadData();

}`
```

Now thing is that if i am posting data from other sub page and then showing it on other sub page. Iam calling addcomment to add posted data in model and then loaddata() to get all data from model for ng-repeat in a view.

if i am going to fire watch event . it will keep on refreshing model thus view data. Suppose i am working on comment section where we can like , dislike and comment on post. and i want to use ng-click event inside ng-repeat(which is refreshing view).

```
Test.controller('Testing',['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){           
         $scope.products = {};           

             $http.post( baseurl+"ajax/getall").success(function(data)
        { 
            $scope.products = data;

         });
             $scope.$watch("products", function(newValue, oldValue) {
 if (newValue === oldValue) { return; } // AKA first run
    $scope.products= newValue;
 });
              });



        $scope.Hello= function(){

            alert("hello");
        }      

    }]);
```

It will keep on refreshing page and thus don't click event inside ng-repeat which is ng-click.
I have fired ng-click="Hello()" event but it doesn't fire.

Comment: You really need to fix the indentation of the code sample and give a better picture on how you are actually calling the methods involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a listener to $scope.data in any part of the application that had a reference to scope. This way, everything will keep up to date when data is updated.

Like so:

$scope.$watch('data', callback)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have used $watch but now my view is keep on refreshing for infinite time because of watch behavior . Review my Question i have updated code thewir. I want view to be refreshed when user post i.e on addComment() function change..

Comment: Now i am not updating data on scope. Watch is outside http.post.But still i am not getting exact solution . I have updated code in post. It is not refreshing on model update

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking the jQuery way. You have to put that away and think data-binding and angularjs.

To do what you are asking is pretty easy if you think the angularjs way.
First of all, you need the php page of yours to print out a html page with a {{updateMe}}

then in your code

```
.success(function(data){
  $scope.updateMe = data
  ......
```

Comment: I understand your concern. Iam using laravel where user post from other page and it is shown in other page of that page template. Now in that case if i am going to post anything in post page . It will not refresh automatically. I need to reload my browser to see changes. Angular data-Binding is best ,Kindly review my updated code.I am  new to this thing.